# Unable to identify syntax error when receiving JSON data from Express Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, es6-promise

I have an express server running which serves JSON data. It serves up data from 3 files when requested from my javascript code. In tha javascript code, I have 3 functions to execute separate http get methods and have synchronized them with Promise.all. For each resolve, I pass the parsed JSON data and it throws the error mentioned in the title. However, the execution does continue and I am able to access the JSON data in the Promise.all block. I looked online and most people had missing braces, etc or incorrect content-type in server response. None of these affected my program at all.

The error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse ()

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Snippets of the source code is provided below:-

**Javascript promise block**

```js
function getposts() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var httpposts = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpposts.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/users");
    httpposts.send();
    httpposts.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
      if(httpposts.readyState==4 & httpposts.status==200){
        resolve(JSON.parse(httpposts.responseText));
      }
    }
  });
}

function getcomments() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var httpcomments = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpcomments.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/comments");
    httpcomments.send();
    httpcomments.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
      //console.log(httpcomments);
      if(httpcomments.readyState==4 & httpcomments.status==200){
        resolve(JSON.parse(httpcomments.responseText));
      }
    }
  });
}

function getuser() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var httpuser = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpuser.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/posts");
    httpuser.send();
    httpuser.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
      if(httpuser.readyState==4 & httpuser.status==200){
        resolve(JSON.parse(httpuser.responseText));
      }
    }
  });
}

Promise.all([getposts(), getcomments(), getuser()]).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  //alert("promise");
  if(window.localStorage.length == 0){
  localStorage.setItem("users", data[2]);
  localStorage.setItem("comments", data[1]);
  localStorage.setItem("posts", data[0]);
}
})
```

**Express Server code**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.get("/users", (req,resp) =>{
fs.readFile("users.json", "utf-8", (err,data)=>{
if(!err) {
resp.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");
resp.status(200).send(data);
console.log("users json data served");
}
})
});

app.get("/comments", (req,resp) =>{
fs.readFile("comments.json", "utf-8", (err,data)=>{
if(!err) {
resp.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");
resp.status(200).send(data);
console.log("comments json data served");
}
})
});

app.get("/posts", (req,resp) =>{
fs.readFile("posts.json", "utf-8", (err,data)=>{
if(!err) {
resp.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");
resp.status(200).send(data);
console.log("posts json data served");
}
})
});

app.use((req,resp)=>{
resp.send("Invalid request.Try <br /> localhost:3000/users<br />  localhost:3000/comments<br /> localhost:3000/posts");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log("server running at 3000");
});
```

**JSON Data Sample**
    [
    {
    "user":"username",
    "org":"hello"
    }
    ]
Actual JSON data is much larger and impractical to post here. This is just a sample I used to test. Both sample and actual data are validated properly and it is not an issue with the data itself.

I tried with setting content-type to "application/json" but the result is the same.
**Edit**
As per suggestions in the comments, data read from the file was actually string. I parsed to JSON before sending it in response and removed the JSON.parse from the front-end but in that case, the error is removed but then data[] just has 3 empty strings.
curl -i http://localhost:3000 says:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 35
ETag: W/"23-kjXHKbaflCAUIVzhPs6BcPM2sOg"
[{"user":"username","org":"hello"}]
```

Note: I removed some irrelevant fields from the output

Comment: What is the error? How are the JSON files generated?

Comment: Just to point out, you're sending back JSON but setting the content type to text/plain. Any reason you're not using application/json?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) is the error. @ Felix Kling

Comment: @Chase it was set to application/json before but a post on stack overflow suggested that text/plain may solve the issue

Comment: and you might be using express... but json isn't generated by express... it's a simple static file you are sending.... and as mentioned in last comment, you should be using application/json
And by the way... to be valid json there is no utf8 chars... only plain ASCI is valid (\u1234 to encode accents...)

Comment: That makes sense. But when I check in the network tab in the browser, the response is data in correct JSON format. @Anthony Gibbs

Comment: perhaps put somewhere (pastebin?) the output of `curl -i http://localhost:3000/users`

Comment: or maybe use a small example JSON dataset because except for the headers and methods name discrepancies the code looks ok.

Comment: A couple things... Are you sure you're sending JSON from the server? It looks like you're just pulling string text from the file and sending that. I would .json() this first. Set content type to application/json - content type will get you every.single.time. They remove the JSON.parse from your front end - parse converts a string, but you've now converted to pure JSON.

Comment: Will implement the changes and check with curl -i and get back to you guys

Comment: I made the changes suggested but it didn't affect the syntax error.

Comment: Have you tried with the sample json you are providing here? This is very likely a json formatting problem, and if you're not providing the json that has the problem... there's not much we'll be able to do

Comment: Yes I am currently using the sample JSON but the problem still persists. I am not going to use the actual JSON data until I fix the issue

Comment: I was really hoping that it would be a JSON formatting problem but the error occurs regardless of what JSON data I use. I even used a couple of JSON validators to make sure of this.

Comment: Have you tried purposely causing an error? If changing the json isn't changing the error, focus on first making sure you can force a particular error. You may not be looking at the right section of code, maybe a different route is handling it or something else. Have you tried skipping the readfile part?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the check for **httpresponse.readyState == 4** is what introduced the issue.

Upon un-commenting that part in my code, it works perfectly. In hindsight, I should have posted the code exactly as it was in my editor, instead of editing it on SO to avoid questions. The promises were resolving before the responses were complete and ready, so the JSON data had an unexpected end of input.